# Laravel-datatables protection

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datatable, datatables

I'm using https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables currently to send ajax request for my datatable but noticed this:

```
columns: [
              { data: 'first_name'  },
                { data: 'last_name' },
                { data: 'email' },                  
        ]
```

but those are lines in my javascript document. I'm currently providing data like this:

```
return Datatables::of(User::all())->make(true);
```

That means if someone change lines in my js file he can view columns that he is not supposed to. Now if you take a look at github documentation you can see that this package can also accept collection or query. Is it possible to target only certain columns from database with collection or query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch only necessary columns from database like this:

```
return Datatables::of(User::all(['first_name','last_name','email']))->make(true);
```

Comment: `DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7`